# Cannot mock for GetRequestHandler

Tags: java, unit-testing, aws-lambda, mocking

I am implementing unit test for below class and I need to mock for object handler that initialize inside handlerRequest method of this class. how to write the unit test?

```
public class ImlRequestHandler implements RequestHandler {

    private static final Map<String, RequestHandler> REQUEST_HANDLERS;

    static {
        REQUEST_HANDLERS= new HashMap<>();
        REQUEST_HANDLERS.put(HttpMethod.GET, new GetRequestHandler());
        REQUEST_HANDLERS.put(HttpMethod.POST, new PostRequestHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(final Map<String, String> request, final Context context) {
        final String userId = request.get(Input.USER_ID);

        final String httpMethod = request.get(Input.HTTP_METHOD);
        final RequestHandler handler = REQUEST_HANDLERS.get(httpMethod);

        if (handler != null) {
            return handler.handleRequest(request, context);
        } else {
            return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .withBody("Bad request");
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to mock like below but nothing changed

```
    GetRequestHandler mockHandler = mock(GetRequestHandler.class);
    APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
    response.setBody("body");
    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    //When
    when(mockHandler.handleRequest(anyMap(),any())).thenReturn(response);
```

Comment: Can you share what is a specific exception did you get when ran the test?